# Oracle dropping last PARTITION for a table

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I'm trying to drop all partitions for a table and I'm running into the following error:

ORA-14083: cannot drop the only partition of a partitioned table ORA-06512:

I know I can drop the table and recreate it but I want to see if my procedure can be modified to use an EXCEPTION that sets the retention to nothing, drops the PARTITION and sets the INTERVAL back to its original value?

Any help and expertise would be greatly appreciated. Below is my test CASE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl(p_cmd varchar2) 
 authid current_user
is
BEGIN 

dbms_output.put_line(p_cmd);

 execute immediate p_cmd;

END;
/

CREATE  OR REPLACE PROCEDURE
drop_partition(
  p_tab varchar2,
  p_date date
) authid current_user
is
  v_high_value date;
    cursor v_cur is
    select table_name,
           partition_name,
           high_value,
           partition_position
    from   user_tab_partitions
    where  table_name = upper(p_tab);
begin
  for v_rec in v_cur loop
    execute immediate 'select ' || v_rec.high_value || ' from dual' into v_high_value;
    if     v_high_value <= trunc(p_date)
           then
      
    -- dbms_output.put_line ('partition ' || v_rec.partition_name || ' high value is ' || to_char(v_high_value,'mm/dd/yyyy'));

--ddl( 'ALTER TABLE ' || p_tab || ' DROP PARTITION FOR(DATE ' || TO_CHAR(v_high_value,'YYYY-MM-DD') || ')');

      ddl('alter table '||p_tab||' drop partition '||v_rec.partition_name);

          end if;    
  end loop;
END;
/

CREATE  TABLE partition_retention
(
  seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
DAYS NUMBER(6),
CONSTRAINT
partition_retention_pk primary key (table_name)); 
/

INSERT into partition_retention(TABLE_NAME, DAYS) 
        WITH data as (
          select 'T1', 0
from dual union all
         select 'T3', 15
from dual union all
        select 'T4', 10
from dual union all
       select 'T5', 5
from dual)
        SELECT * from data;
/

CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-02-01')
select dt from dt;
/

BEGIN
    FOR td IN
    (
        SELECT table_name
        ,      NVL (pr.days, 30) AS days
        FROM       user_part_tables     pt
          JOIN       user_part_key_columns pkc ON pkc.name = pt.table_name
          JOIN       user_tab_cols         tc  USING (table_name, column_name)
        LEFT JOIN partition_retention   pr  USING (table_name)
        WHERE       pkc.object_type     = 'TABLE'
        AND       pt.partitioning_type = 'RANGE'
        AND REGEXP_LIKE (tc.data_type, '^DATE$|^TIMESTAMP.*')
        ORDER BY table_name
    )
    LOOP
                      
      drop_partition(
          td.table_name,
  trunc(sysdate-td.days)
         );
      END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: [You cannot drop the only partition in the table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e12700.htm#1656). What do you want to achieve?

Comment: A table  that contains only one Oracle partition cannot be dropped,  you must drop the table or you can truncate the Partition or recreate the table without any partitions depends upon what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says "drop the **last** partition" which can be different to "drop the **only** partition"

As stated already in comments, you cannot drop the partition when only one partition is left. If you like to remove the data, then you can **TRUNCATE** the partition.

This PL/SQL Block should cover all your cases:

```
CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0) --> More generic than number of days
);



DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

    CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION, -14083);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
 
   CURSOR TablePartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, p.HIGH_VALUE, t.INTERVAL, RETENTION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES t
        JOIN USER_TAB_PARTITIONS p USING (TABLE_NAME)
        JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pk ON pk.NAME = TABLE_NAME
        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS tc USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
        JOIN PARTITION_RETENTION r USING (TABLE_NAME);
  
BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TablePartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - aPart.RETENTION THEN
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dropped partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot drop the only partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Truncated partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                    BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Drop last partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL ()';
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' DROP PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME;
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';            
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN 
                            -- Depending on the order the "last" partition can be also the "only" partition at the same time
                            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cannot drop the only partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME|| ' UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
                            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Truncated partittion '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                    END;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: So if I have only 1 PARTITION the sample code you posted should work? Since I have several it will not work? I'm a bit confused by your statement

Comment: Please see my update. If your table has only one partition then it just do nothing due to `WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, clarification and update. I understand now

Comment: thanks for the update. I tried it and the error is gone but I'm left with 3 partitions 1/29, 1/30 & 1/31 where I was only expecting 1 PARTITION 1/31. Can you please elaborate. Is there a problem with my code. I Thanks for your time and expertise

Comment: Please see my update, it is more generic. For me it is working

Comment: Thanks for your time and expertise but unfortunately I can't seem to get your last update to compile using livesql. I'll keep searching the for a solution as I prefer using a wrapper to pass in VALUES and I can call a procedure to rebuild all invalid indexes at once in the wrapper when all the PARTITIONs are dropped. I recall seeing something about update global indexes go away at sometime? If your curious I can post ALL my code

Comment: Why do you need parameter? All information is available in your `partition_retention` table. Anyway, converting the anonymous PL/SQL block into a procedure with specific parameter should be no big deal. Where do you face the problem?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 11, column 66:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "RETENTION": invalid identifier. Should it be retention_day?  CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
   seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION_DAY INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0) 
);

insert into PARTITION_RETENTION (TABLE_NAME, RETENTION_DAY) 
select 'T1', interval '0' day from dual union all
select 'T3', interval '15' day from dual union all
select 'T4', 15 * interval '1' day from dual union all
select 'T5', 5 * interval '1 00:00:00' day to second from dual;

Comment: As for the wrapper how I also use it to feed ONLY range INTERVAL into the procedure. I guess I can move that code into your procedure as I would only want to maintain 1 piece of code instead of two.

Comment: Yes, was a typo. Now the `CREATE TABLE` statement works

Comment: Perfect works great. I'll see about adding a CONSTRAINT to the PARTITION RETENTION table to only add range INTERVAL tables and rebuild indexes instead of update global indexes when all the PARTITIONs are dropped. Thanks for your help and expertise!!!